# An example of a Deligne–Lusztig variety for a general linear group

Tags: reductive-groups, borel-sets, deligne-lusztig-theory

Take $G=\operatorname{GL}_3$, defined over the algebraic closure of a  finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and let $X$ be the set of Borel subgroups of $G$.
The Frobenius morphism $F:G\to G$ induces a map $F:X\to X$, as $G/B\cong X$ for any chosen Borel subset $B$.
The Weyl group $W$ of $G$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_3$, and we have a bijection between $W$ and the set of $G$-orbits on $X\times X$.
Fix a Borel subset $B^+\in X$.
For $w\in W$, define $\mathcal{O}(w)$ to be the orbit of $(B^+,\dot wB^+\dot w^{-1})$ in $X\times X$.
We say that $B_1,B_2\in X$ are in relative position $w$ if $(B_1,B_2)\in\mathcal{O}(w)$.

For any $w\in W$, we can define the Deligne–Lusztig variety associated to it as $X(w)=\{B\in X:B\text{ and }F(B)\text{ are in relative position }w\}$.

**My Question**

I want to compute $X((1\ 2))$.

I know that $X$ can be identified with the full flag variety $\mathcal{F}_3$, but how I can interpret the condition of $B$ and $F(B)$ being in relative position $w$ in terms of flags?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Terminology: you say that you want to take $G = \operatorname{GL}_{3\,\overline{\mathbb F_q}}$; but you actually want $G = \operatorname{GL}_{3\,\mathbb F_q}$, or else there is no canonical Frobenius endomorphism of $G_{\overline{\mathbb F_q}}$.

Comment: Thanks! I think what I wanted to say is that I take $G_0=\text{GL}_{3,\mathbb{F}_q}$ and then  $G=G_0\times_{\mathbb{F}_q}\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$, the base change to the algebraic closure. Do you agree?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447030/an-example-of-a-deligne-lusztig-variety-for-a-general-linear-group#comment1155118_447030), yes, I agree.  (I meant $G_0 \times_{\mathbb F_q} \overline{\mathbb F_q}$ by $(G_0)_{\overline{\mathbb F_q}}$.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{F}\colon V_1\subseteq\dotsb\subseteq V_n$ and $\mathcal{F}'\colon U_1\subseteq\dotsb\subseteq U_n$ be two complete flags. Then $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}'$ are said to be in relative position $w$, where $w\in S_n$ is a permutation, if
$$\dim V_i\cap U_j=\#(\{ 1,\dotsc,i \}\cap \{ w(1),\dots,w(j) \})$$
for any $i,j\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}$.

In particular, the variety $X((1\ 2))$ consists of the flags $V_1\subseteq V_2$ in which $V_2$ is an $F$-stable plane and $V_1$ is an $F$-unstable line. So it is
$$\operatorname{Gr}(1,3)^F\times \mathbb{P}^1\setminus\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_q),$$
a disjoint union of copies of the Drinfeld curve.

Computations like this are very useful for making explicit connections with combinatorics. For a reference, you may want to take a look at Steinberg's paper *[An occurrence of the Robinson–Schensted correspondence](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(88)90177-9)*.

Comment: Yes, it means the complement.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447030/an-example-of-a-deligne-lusztig-variety-for-a-general-linear-group/447051#comment1154994_447051), OK, I edited accordingly.

Comment: Many many thanks!! This is exactly what I need. I guess that I now need to show why this works, i.e. that a Borel subgroup $B$ is in relative position $w$ with $F(B)$ exactly if the flags are in relative position $w$. Do you have any hints?

Comment: You may first transfer to the standard upper triangular Borel, then take a standard basis on which the permutations permute.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "transfer to the standard upper triangular Borel"? Suppose we denote this Borel subgroup by $B^+$, and another Borel $B$ is in relative position $w$ with $F(B)$. Do you mean that there is a $g\in G$ such that $B=gB^+g^{-1}$ and $F(B)=g\dot w B^+\dot w^{-1}g^{-1}$? Here, I am using the orbit definition of relative position.

Comment: There is no need to stick to the Frobenius of Borel: By definition, a pair of two Borels are in relative position $w$ if it lies in the $G$-orbit of the pair $(B^+,wB^+w^{-1})$, so you can just try to figure out the relations between the flags associated to $B^+$ and $wB^+w^{-1}$.

Comment: OK. The flag associated to $B^+$ is the standard flag, and because $\dot w^{-1}=\dot w$ (I am taking $w=(1\ 2)$), we have that $\dot w B^+\dot w^{-1}$ also fixes the standard basis. I am confused what the flag associated to $\dot w B^+\dot w^{-1}$ should be exactly. From the relative position formula, I know that the one dimensional space should have trivial intersection with $\langle e_1\rangle$. But this does not seem to be the case if $\dot w B^+\dot w^{-1}$ fixes $\langle e_1\rangle$?