# Relative position of Borel subgroups for the symplectic group

Tags: reductive-groups, flag-varieties, deligne-lusztig-theory

**Background**

Let $n$ be a positive integer, let $W$ be the Weyl group of $\text{GL}_n$.
Its set of Borel subgroups is isomorphic to the full flag variety $\mathcal{F}_n$.

In this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447030/an-example-of-a-deligne-lusztig-variety-for-a-general-linear-group), I studied what it meant for two Borel subgroups to be in relative position $w\in W$ in terms of the flag variety $\mathcal{F}_n$.

**My question**

I now want to do the same for the symplectic group.
To make things easier, I want to restrict to $G=\text{Sp}_4$ with symplectic basis $(e_1,e_2,e_2',e_1')$.
I want to understand what it means for a Borel subgroup $B\subset G$ to be in relative position $w=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\\\
1&0\end{pmatrix}$ with the Borel subgroup $B^+$ of symplectic upper triangular matrices, in terms of the flag variety $G/B^+\subset \mathcal{F}_4$.
To this end, suppose that $(B^+,B)\in\mathcal{O}(w)$ and note that $w$ permutes the symplectic basis.

The standard Borel $B^+$ corresponds to the flag $V^+\colon \langle e_1\rangle \subset \langle e_1,e_2\rangle \subset \langle e_1,e_2,e_2'\rangle$, and that $B=g\dot w B^+\dot w^{-1}g^{-1}$ (for some $g\in B^+$, as $B^+$ and $B$ are in relative position $w$) corresponds to the flag $V\colon \langle e_1'\rangle \subset \langle e_1',e_2'\rangle \subset \langle e_1',e_2',e_2\rangle$. Now, similar to the case of the general linear group, we have that $$\dim V_i^+\cap V_j=|\{b_1,\ldots,b_i\}\cap \{w(b_1),\ldots,w(b_j)\}|$$ where $b_l=\begin{cases}e_l\text{ if }l\leq 2\\\\e_l'\text{ if }l> 2\end{cases}$ and $0\leq i,j\leq 3$.
We denote this property by $V^+\xrightarrow{w}V$.

I want to claim that $B^+\xrightarrow{w}B$ if and only if $V^+\xrightarrow{w}V$, just as in the general linear case.
Is this true?